# How can I get specific range of array just in specific range index by PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array like this (PHP Code):

```
$my_arr=array(0=>"Joe",1=>"Mike",2=>"Simo","Peter"=>"35", 3=>"Ben" , "Ben"=>"37", 4=>"Nik" , "Joe"=>"43");
```

I want just get values specific range of index and replace previous arrays values with these new values.Something like this:

```
$rang= 0-4 OR 0,1,2,3,4 //range of index values.
$my_arr= filtered array value in range index of $range.
```

I want get this result:

```
$my_arr=array(0=>"Joe",1=>"Mike",2=>"Simo", 3=>"Ben" , 4=>"Nik");
```

How should I do this?

**Update:**

**I just want to separate the values of the array($my_arr) that are within the range of the specified number of indexes and everywhere in the array and replace all previous array($my_arr) values with these new values.**

## **

**If there were not some of the indexes, Other indexes outside of the specified range for index numbers should not be replaced and only return values of indexes between 0 and 4($my_arr[0]....$my_arr[4]) , and if they don't have value leave empty or do not return something else**

Comment: Amm... array_slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution after several tests:

```
foreach($my_arr as $indx=>$val )
   {
       if(is_int($indx) && ($indx>=0 && $indx<=4))
       {
           $my_arr[$indx]= $val; 
        }
       else
       { continue; }

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**array_slice**

> Extract a slice of the array

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

Since your array contains mixed keys, you should first sort it so the numeric keys would appear first.

According to your code:

```
ksort($my_arr, SORT_NATURAL);
$my_sliced_arr = array_slice($my_arr, 0, 4);
```

Output:

```
//var_dump($my_sliced_arr)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Joe"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Mike"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Simo"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "Ben"
}
```

- [Manual array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [Manual ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: array_slice removes the elements designated by offset and length from the input array, and replaces them with the elements of the replacement array, if supplied.
BUT I just want to separate the values of the array that are within the range of the specified number of indexes and everywhere in the array and replace all previous arrays values with these new values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.If some elements of the array, for example, the index 2 does not exist What happens? Doesn't display error?

Comment: I want If there were not some of the indexes, Other indexes outside of the specified range for index numbers should not be replaced and only return values of indexes between 0 and 4($my_arr[0]....$my_arr[4]) , and if they don't have value leave empty or do not return something else

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$my_arr=array(0=>"Joe",1=>"Mike",2=>"Simo","Peter"=>"35", 3=>"Ben" , "Ben"=>"37", 4=>"Nik" , "Joe"=>"43");
$numerickeys = array_filter(array_keys($my_arr), 'is_int');
foreach($numerickeys as $num)
{
  $ar2[$num] = $my_arr[$num];
}
print_r($ar2);
```